# How to format a date value for Hubspot API using Python

Tags: python, hubspot

I have read the docs saying that to pass the value for a Hubspot date field you should format your Date as *midnight* UTC. However, I've had no luck doing so in Python. I assume I am just missing the magic Python incantation that will get the right result. Here is what I have:

```
    from pytz import timezone, utc
    from hubspot.crm.contacts import SimplePublicObject,

    created_dt = # datetime from sqlalchemy query
    utcdt = utc.localize(
        datetime(
            year=created_dt.year,
            month=created_dt.month,
            day=created_dt.day
            )
    )
    ts = int(utcdt.timestamp())
    props = SimplePublicObjectInput({"last_booking": str(ts)})
    return client.crm.companies.basic_api.update(
        hs_id, simple_public_object_input=props
    )
```

this returns this error:

```
{"status":"error",
 "message":"Property values were not valid: [{\"isValid\":false,\"message\":\"1570233600 is at 4:10:33.600 UTC, not midnight!\"...
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Ah, the answer was right there. Python `timestamp` returns the time in seconds, and HubSpot expects milliseconds. I just had to multiply by 1000:

```
ts = int(utcdt.timestamp()*1000)
```

now all looks good.

Comment: This solution works for a Hubspot datetime, but will cause an error if the Hubspot field is a "Date Picker" property type (which is date only).   https://legacydocs.hubspot.com/docs/faq/how-should-timestamps-be-formatted-for-hubspots-apis

Comment: For dates, the docs say "Date properties will only store the date, and must be set to midnight UTC for the date you want."

Answer (score 0):

did you try adding hours and minutes to your datetime call

```
datetime(
    year=created_dt.year,
    month=created_dt.month,
    day=created_dt.day,
    hour=0,
    minute=0
)
```

Comment: Nope, same result. I also set second=0, microsecond=0. Pretty sure these are the default.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Hubspot supported "sanetime" module:  https://github.com/HubSpot/sanetime

Then to get a date:

```
yourdate = datetime.datetime.date()
hubspot_date = sanetime.time(yourdate )
```

Or if you do not want a dependency:

```
#convert datetime to UTC
your_utc_datetime = your_datetime.astimezone(pytz.UTC)

#replace time with midnight
your_utc_date_midnight = your_utc_datetime.replace(hour=0,minute=0,second=0, microsecond=0)

# convert to epoch (Python 3.3+)
your_hubspot_date = your_utc_date_midnight.timestamp()*1000
```